# What is equivalent data type of float[] in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion

What is the Visual Basic equivalent statement of the following code?

```cs
float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f };
```

Comment: As [Croll alludes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693481/what-is-equivalent-data-type-of-float-in-vb-net#comment55158725_33693540), this may already have been a mega duplicate at the time. What is the canonical question? Answers at least ought to contain references to services and tools that can be used to automate such translations.

Answer (score 6):

Here, `float` can be represented as `Single` with the `F` suffix too:

```vb
Dim widths As Single() = {1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F}
```

Ref.: *[How to: Initialize an Array Variable in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable)*

Answer (score 5):

`float` type  accessed with name `Single` in Visual Basic. `float` is Visual C# keyword only.

[Define an array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) of `System.Single`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx)

```
Dim widths() as Single = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
```

> Use the Single data type to contain floating-point values that do not
>   require the full data width of Double. In some cases the common
>   language runtime might be able to pack your Single variables closely
>   together and save memory consumption.

Comment: exactly the same as my answer ?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah This happens a lot when you answer "speed typing contest" questions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it's always pleasure to answer 100 times previously disuccsed questions for noobs and earn small rep. That's how it works.